# mCustomScrollbar jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

Here's my HTML, first the `<div id="tablebody">`, I used a script that appends a `<tr>` content inside these div which has a css property of "`overflow:auto`".

Once the contents have overflowed inside, the scroll-bar always appeared by default which was supposed to be the customized one from `mCustomScrollbar` from the script I called.

I don't know how to make it fires the div's scroll-bar..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css"/>       

<script  src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script >
 <!--script of the plugin-->
    <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load( function(){

        $('#tablebody').mCustomScrollbar({               
            scrollButtons:(enable:true),
            autoHideScrollbar:true

        });

    });
)}(jquery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tablebody"> <!--css{overflow:auto}-->
   <table id="inv_data">
        <tbody id="data_content"></tbody> <!--appending <tr>-->
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and where is `m` defined?

Comment: sorry i got mistaken that was mCustomScrollbar

Comment: Have you tried calling it from within $(document).ready() ?

Comment: yes i've tried that,, but also didn't worked

Comment: Have you checked the plugin's src filepath is correct?

Comment: they're all in the same folder i'm so confused except the other scripts are from js folder

Comment: It could be that the parentheses are the wrong way round in your last line - you have `)}(jquery);` instead of `})(jquery);`

Comment: yah...thanks but still didnt work..i'm so confused

Comment: May be you need to add a `max-height` to the div. And also add an option to `mCustomScrollbar()` initialization i.e. `advanced:{updateOnContentResize: true}`.. This should work for you.